# How to run a joint query using spring jpa?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Below is the query used to fetch details from the employee table and address table. There more columns in the tables which as of now not required.

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.name   ,
    e.address_id,
    a.city
FROM
    employee   e,
    address a
WHERE
    e.id = 1
    AND a.id = e.address_id;
```

How to run this query using spring JPA, and map it to a model class as below?

```
public class Employee {
    long id;
    Stirng name;
    String city;
    long addressId;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an employee repository? If you don't have one. You need one. Then you can can write a JPA join query. You need to create a DTO to retrieve query results from employee and address like employeedetailsDTO.

Comment: do you have entities mapped to the `address` and `employee` table respectively?